# Is there a way to simulate an M/M/C queue where each process requires more than one processor?

Tags: queue, simulation, distribution, montecarlo, multiprocessor

I have a CSV with 100k processes with their respective Interarrival time, Service Time and # of processors required. I did simulation in Python but it was not even close to the theoretical results.
However, I can't seem to find any reference to this particular kind of system so I could maybe look at some examples. In my head, it must be done using concurrency within the used language but I'm sure there's a better way.

[Code](https://pastebin.com/XZUmZJN0)

```
for i in range(len(tproc)):
        if tproc[i] == 100000:
            k = i
        else:
            for j in range(len(tproc)):
                if tproc[i] <= tproc[j]:
                    k = i

    if Tarrival <= tproc[k]:
        if n > 100000:
            dr += 1
            z = - Tb * math.log(random.random())
            Tarrival = T + z
```

...

This is the first simulation we had but this generates random values and only has 5 processors, whereas we need 1500 processors and values from the existing table.

Comment: knowing what type of queue this is would also be helpful...

Comment: What is CSV in this context?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux csv contains the jobs that arrive to the system. Each row is a job and there are 3 columns: InterArrival Time, Service Time and # of processors needed.

Comment: You haven't said anything about the queue discipline.  You'll get different results depending on whether it's a staight first-come-first-served vs jobs with lower processor requirements are processed when larger jobs are blocked vs LIFO vs shortest-processing-time-first vs round-robin scheduling vs ...